# Remove string with regexp leaving only ones with img tag inside - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that contains content previously formatted by WP and it contains few types of `[caption]` tags. Examples:

> [caption (attributes here)]some text[/caption]
>
> [caption (attributes here)]©name and surname[/caption]
>
> [caption id="attachment_49532" align="aligncenter" width="530"][/caption]

I need to remove only the ones that contain `©` followed by the name of the person.

I tried:

```
preg_replace("/\[caption(.*?)\]©(.*?)\[\/caption\]/","",$string);
```

but it does the job only if as input string I have only one [caption] tag like

```
$string = "[caption (parameters here)]©name and surname[/caption]";
```

and not the string with more elements inside.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: There is regex for you https://www.regex101.com/r/oJ5nX6/1

Comment: Can you provide an example of `the string with more elements inside`? Do you mean `[caption (attributes here)][bold]test[/bold]©name and surname[/caption]`?

Comment: What if `]©` is in one of the attribute values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable DOTALL modifier, so that it would make dot in your regex to match also the line breaks.

```
preg_replace('/\[caption\b.*?\]©.*?\[\/caption\]/su',"",$string);
```